# Adding multiple records on a form using jquery

Tags: jquery, webforms

I have an events form that allows someone to add a new event. An event can have multiple locations, what I want to do using jquery is on the add form give them the ability to add multiple locations before they submit the form. I have an idea of how to have the form setup to add multiple locations but the question is what is the best way to store the multiple locations added by the user so I can display it on the form as they add them as well as re-display them if the person submits the form and they forgot a required field?

****EDIT****

To give more information of what Im trying to accomplish on the form I was looking at having a link that says add location, then a pop up comes up asking for the address of this location. Once they enter the location they click add and then that location shows on the form. Then they can repeat that step to add additional locations. Once done the form shows all locations to add for that event, then the person submits the form and I can loop through the locations added via the form so I can add them into the database. So how would I store the locations in the form to accomplish that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE
Correct answer is in comments below:
Create a "Location" table in the db with each location, and all of the fields associated with it. Then you can just use the location id in your array, and then when iterating through the array you can pull all of the associated fields for that location id.

If you're using JQuery UI you may want to consider some of the JQuery MultiSelect Plugins:

http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jquery-multiselect

To get the checked values to display to the user on the form, as well as if there are any errors, call the appropriate method ('getChecked' if you're using the jQuery UI MultiSelect Widget) to get an array of all the checked checkboxes.

Comment: Thanks for the info. That doesnt look like exactly what Im looking for. The locations have multiple fields such as street, city, state zip etc. So Im looking to add multiple locations on one form then be able to submit it and loop through it so I can add it to the db.

Comment: @John I see. Hmm that's a bit more challenging. What language are you using? Since you're loading a new page on each form submit you could declare a blank list/array, and then with each form submission add the id for that location to the list/array. You could then set a JQuery variable to your list/array value, and then have something to iterate through when posting the data to the db. Kind of a hack but might do the trick.

Comment: @John found a tutorial that might be helpful: http://www.chromaticsites.com/blog/jquery-tutorial-selecting-multiple-select-form-elements-on-the-fly/

Comment: Im using PHP. I was planning on using a temp table so when someone went to the event form a unique key would be generated and each location added would be created in the temp table and tracked by the unique id. But before doing all of that was trying to find a less intensive solution that maybe puts all fields into an array that I can access via the form. But where I get lost is each location requires multiple fields.

Comment: @John how about creating a "Location" table in the db with each location, and all of the fields associated with it. Then you can just use the location id in your array, and then when iterating through the array you can pull all of the associated fields for that location id. Would that work?

Answer (score 0):

When they click to add a location I would provide another form in a lightbox, and when they submit that - close the lightbox and just add it (with their content) into the original form). Hopefully that's what you're trying to accomplish. Good luck!

Comment: @DropTheNerd Yes that is what I want it to do, but enable them to do that for multiple locations. How would I store the location added via lightbox in a variable that I can process once the form has been submitted? The location will have multiple fields as well.

Comment: Well, you could just add them back to the initial form as new inputs with the user's data - or set them to hidden fields with the user's data and it would get submitted along with the rest of the form. Otherwise you'd want to store them in a session, but that could get very messy very quickly.

Comment: @DropTheNerd I was thinking because there are multiple fields required to just create a unique id when a new event is being added and just store the locations in a temp table and use jquery ajax to dynamically load all locations that were added via the form for this event and just query the table when the person submits the form. I just felt that was extreme but looks like its the only viable solution.

Comment: Since there are multiple location fields that would be the same, just name them like so, location[1], location[2], etc. Then on your post just foreach($_POST['location'] as $k => $v) to get the multiple locations.

Comment: @DropTheNerd The problem is there are multiple fields for each location. Street field, city field, state field, zip code field. And each location needs to be added into the event locations table in the database so I need each field to be broken out for db entry.

Comment: Perhaps try naming them location[1][street], location[1][city], location[1][state]... You should be able to access everything you'd need when submitted then.

Comment: @DropTheNerd The only thing I can think of instead of using a temp table in the db is to have each field stored in a array seperated by a unique character and explode it using jquery to show the locations added in the form and explode it in php when the form is submitted. Example locations[][street<>city<>state<>zip] and explode it by <>